# Finding an intermediate subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given three finite abelian group with strict inclusion $$A'\subsetneq A''\subsetneq A,$$ is there a "canonical" way to find a subgroup $H$ with $A'\subset H\subset A$ such that, $A''\cap H=A'$ and $A/A''\simeq H/A'$?

I said a "canonical" way since I think using classification of finite abelian groups, all groups involved can be written as forms
$$\bigoplus_{i=1}^k\mathbb Z/n_i\mathbb Z$$
and  probably we can always find such a group by playing around $n_i$ and $k$. However, it is a bit too "artificial" to me. I am wondering if there is an "abstract" way to construct or prove the existence of such a group without using that classification.

Comment: Take $A=\mathbb Z$, $A'=4\mathbb Z$, $A''=2\mathbb Z$. Then $A''$ is unique (with this property).

Comment: You can assume WLOG that $A'$ is trivial or (if you prefer) you can assume that $A$ is free. I can't see any point in trying to avoid using the classification of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: My comment was to prove that $A''$ is unique, and so no such $H$ exists in general.

Comment: For finite groups (assuming $A'=1$) I believe the answer should be 'if and only if $\gcd(|A''|,|A/A''|)=1$. For other cases either there is no such $H$ or there is but there is no canonical such choice. (I have not double-checked this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is *not* a canonical way to find such a subgroup $H$.
In fact, such $H$ does not necessarily exist.

Consider $0\subsetneq2\mathbb Z\subsetneq\mathbb Z$. Then no subgroup $H\subseteq\mathbb Z$ satisfies
$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\simeq H$.

---

(Added for comment)

I will give an example of *finite* abelian groups which do not have such $H$. Let $A=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. Consider
$$
0\subsetneq2A\subsetneq A.
$$
A subgroup $H\subseteq A$ such that $H\simeq A/2A\simeq\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is only the subgroup $2A$. Hence the condition $2A\cap H=0$ can not be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your example! That's great. If you dont mind, would you mind thinking a bit about the case when we only consider finite abelian group? I just realized only finite abelian group is interesting to me

Comment: I have added in my answer an example $A=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ for *finite* cases!